# Weird issue with calculations when I use an if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an excel sheet which looks like the following: (Ive taken out all the irelevant information)

[image]

Column `D` is a formula that has been dragged down to all cells (changing the row number):

`=IF(A2 = "",$D1-C2,A2 - C2)`

If you see cell `D6` you will notice it has some sort of error. Ive included 2 examples. The bottom half of the table is working correctly with the same formula. The first section is not working and I assume its because of the 0.985, it seems to only happen when its above 0.9 but below 1.

Is anyone able to help figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Interesting little round-off thing going on. If all the 1's are exactly 1 and the .985 is exactly .985 and the error still appears, given its size I would just round column D to the nearest integer with ROUND(<your current formula>,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a rounding error on floating point numbers (see [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more info). You can resolve this issue by using `round` on certain number of decimal places, e.g.
`round(D6, 3)` would round D6 to the 3 decimal places for better precision, if that is what you need.

Comment: Thought that may be the case. Just a little hesitant since its over 300,000 records to change in different files because the company I work for doesn't have any sort of naming conventions. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, it's scientific notation. The value it's displaying is `3.33*10^(-16)`, or 0.00000000000000333067 (hope I counted that right).

It's basically a rounding error. If you'd like the column to show zero for values close to zero, then format the column as a number with a limited number of decimal places.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant it was an error in what it was outputting (not mistaking the E for error) as  surely it should be consistent? The issue with formatting it as a number is that I have other formulas referencing that cell and VBA, I assume I would have to also put in some sort of rounding in those too? Or does it take the formatted cell value when I reference it in VBA?